# Find Maytag Upright Freezer Coils

Tags: repair, cleaning, freezer

How do I access the freezer coils? Do I need to remove the door? Photo is of the front of the freezer.

[image]

Comment: The evaporator coils in an upright are usually in the back behind a panel that controls the air flow. The condenser coils can be under the exterior skin or under the bottom of the unit. Your model and why you are looking for a coil may provide answers with useful information.

Comment: Hmm...re photo. MZF34X16DW00

Comment: Added photo again!

Comment: I would like to clean the coils. It is 5 years old and is not holding temperature. It is at 30 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning would I dictate condenser coil.
You will have to pull it out, there is usually a section at the bottom it may have a cardboard cover.
On some units there is a fan, this fan can fail cleaning the area and lube of the fan bearings can revive a fan that may not be doing its job, dirty coils can also reduce the efficiency.

The worst plugged up fan I have ever found had a mouse (dead) stuck in the fan stopping it from turning.

These motors are normally shaded pole and hard to kill if the fan is not spinnng a few drops of light oil on the bushings at either end should help it. These are oil lite “bearings” and there is a wick that is filled with oil the bronze bushing is wetted by the oil and they usually last for years, if stuck adding oil and spinning by hand usually will revive them. The more oil you can get to soak into the wicks the longer it will work. ( I take them apart and Saturate them and get 5 years usually.)